# Garage catch basin and basement washroom drain pipe connection

Tags: plumbing, basement, garage, rough-in

I am trying to get a good understanding of the plumbing setup I have in the garage (see attached picture).

This catch-basin is located in the middle of the garage. There is a basement washroom on the other side of the garage wall and the drain connection seems to be routed and connected to the ABS "municipal pipe" in the garage catch basin.

I would like to know the following:

1. Is this an acceptable or common setup? Or does something need to be changed?
2. What kind of work can I do to I improve this catch basin setup? For example, I would like to at least make it a square shape so I can put a proper metal square grate as a lid for it. Would I be able to add some concrete mix to "square out" the basin? (as long as I keep the pipe entrance clear)

Thanks,

Vlad

[image]

Comment: So that lower pipe is just open to the sewer? Can't smell good. Ick. You would want some signficant re-work to install a properly trapped floor drain here (you would apparently need to cut some additional concrete for that purpose - then you could use a larger grate, or just extend the cleanout accesses and fill the rest of this with concrete.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes you are right there is a smell coming out so that's another issue to resolve. I am understanding now that I will have to contact some local plumbing companies to advance with this project!